# Convert geodetic to topocentric coordinates in pyproj

Tags: proj, pyproj, geodetic, topocentric

I'm trying to convert between topocentric coordinates and geographic coordinates with pyproj.

First, I made a topocentric CRS using the proj4 string from the example [here](https://proj.org/operations/conversions/topocentric.html). Then, I made a geodetic CRS using EPSG:4326. The `Transformer` gave me issues when I tried to make the conversion. Code here:

```py
from pyproj import CRS
from pyproj import Transformer

crs_4326 = CRS.from_epsg(4326)
crs_topo = CRS.from_proj4(f"+proj=topocentric +ellps=WGS84 +lon_0=5 +lat_0=55 +h_0=200")
Transformer.from_crs(crs_4326, crs_topo, always_xy=True)
```

I get this error:
`ProjError: Input is not a transformation.: (Internal Proj Error: pipeline: Pipeline: Mismatched units between step 1 and 2)`

How can I use a `Transformer` to convert to or from a topocentric system?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/discussions/863

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question trying to solve the same problem in C. Here's what I came up with as a solution to my problem, which may be similar to yours.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <proj.h>

int main(void)
{
    PJ_CONTEXT *C;
    PJ *P;
    PJ_COORD a, b;

    C = proj_context_create();
    
    P = proj_create(C, "proj=pipeline step proj=cart ellps=WGS84 step proj=topocentric ellps=WGS84 lon_0=-74 lat_0=40 h_0=0");
    a = proj_coord(-74.0, 40.1, 0, 2020);

    a.lpzt.lam = proj_torad(a.lpzt.lam);
    a.lpzt.phi = proj_torad(a.lpzt.phi);

    b = proj_trans(P, PJ_FWD, a);
    
    printf("east %fmeters, north %fmeters, height %fmeters\n", b.enu.e, b.enu.n, b.enu.u);
    
    proj_destroy(P);
    proj_context_destroy(C);
}
```

Compiles with `gcc test.c -lproj`, outputs: `east 0.000000meters, north 11103.553727meters, height -9.689709meters`. Note the lack of `+` in the proj string, and the conversion from degrees to radians.

I gleaned this by creating a debug build of proj 9.0.0, and debugging the cct program. The manual gives this as a command line example:

```
echo 2.12955 53.80939444 73 2020 | cct -d 3 +proj=pipeline +step +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=topocentric +ellps=WGS84 +lon_0=5 +lat_0=55 +h_0=200
```

and in debugging this I found the proj string created from the command line parameters, and the conversion from degrees to radians. Et voila!

The lat/lon I've used in my example C code are, roughly New York City. The coordinate `a` lat/lon are exactly 0.1 degrees north of the topocentric origin I put in the proj string, and reassuringly the northing that is output is +11.1km (which is about right).

Comment: Ahhh thanks a ton, I did not realize the C/C++ runtime interface doesn't like the preceding '+' for args like it does at command line.

Comment: @mr3 no worries. I remember going nuts trying to work this out, the documentation left me floundering, confused and dazed. Definitely one worth putting up here!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (from @snowman2 's link):

```py
from pyproj import CRS
from pyproj import Transformer


t = Transformer.from_pipeline("+proj=pipeline +step +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=topocentric +ellps=WGS84 +lon_0=5 +lat_0=55 +h_0=200")
# Check a point close to the specified origin
t.transform(5.0001, 55.0001, 201)
# (6.399598230444809, 11.132708495215015, 0.9999870808796674)
```

The two-step pipeline here is also described in this section at the bottom of your link: https://proj.org/operations/conversions/topocentric.html#topocentric-origin-described-as-geographic-coordinates

I'm using pyproj==3.3.1, proj==8.0.1.